# Exploratory factor analysis (EFA) for transcriptomic data

Tags: r, factor-analysis, confirmatory-factor, exploratory-data-analysis, false-discovery-rate

I am doing an EFA for transcriptomic data (n=202, p=190). I did log-transformed the data because of skewness.

My question is, do I have to do false discovery rate (FDR) analysis at all prior to my EFA.

Thank you

Comment: Have you look into the package `DESeq2` for R? It has already all of these steps included in the pipeline. Here's the link: http://bioconductor.org/packages/devel/bioc/vignettes/DESeq2/inst/doc/DESeq2.html

Comment: may I ask you what's the purpose of applying EFA here?

Comment: The purpose of EFA here is to see if you have underlying construct/relationship (here it will be a biological and/or immunological pathway). I used DESeq2 for FDR before, I would check if it does EFA. I am using fa and factanal functions.